# Is the mirror Captain Philippa Georgiou a member of Starfleet?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

The crew addresses her as Captain Georgiou several times in *Such Sweet Sorrow* but she has no uniform. Why is she still wearing s&m gear and being addressed as "captain" on the bridge of the Discovery?

Comment: This was explained in season 1. In order to allow her to work for Starfleet and keep the mirror universe a secret, she's posing as the Prime Universe Georgiou who they claimed was not dead but was rescued.

Comment: @BrianOrtiz Please make your last comment an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Mirror!Georgiou negotiates with Sarek the terms of her freedom in "The war without, the war within":

> **GEORGIOU**: You face annihilation. Is it not logical to do anything you can to save the lives of your kind? Give me what I want, and I can assure victory for the Federation.
>   **SAREK**: What are your terms?
>   **GEORGIOU**: Freedom.

As a result, Mirror!Georgiou is now posing as the real one, as seen in the last scene of that episode. The speech given by Admiral Cornwell strongly implies that this move is a desperate measure taken by Starfleet:

> **CORNWELL**: Open a shipwide channel. We have all mourned the enormous loss of life due to this war. The acts of violence committed against us are the acts of a foe without reason, without honour. And they will not stop coming after us in the hopes of destroying everything that we hold dear. **These are desperate times, and they call on us to do more than merely protect our people, defend our borders.** (...) . So allow me to introduce you to the person who will chart your course to Qo'noS. Captain Philippa Georgiou.
>   **GEORGIOU**: Thank you.
>   **CORNWELL**: Though long presumed dead, Captain Georgiou was recently rescued in a highly classified raid of a Klingon prison vessel. She was transported aboard Discovery with my personal retinue. The mission to Qo'noS is a perilous expedition, and Starfleet is confident that Captain Georgiou is uniquely qualified to get you there and to do what needs to be done.
>   **GEORGIOU**: Specialist Burnham, I trust that this will be an auspicious reunion, despite our history. Now take your station.
>   **BURNHAM**: Yes, Captain.

So in short: Mirror!Georgiou is posing as the real Georgiou, who is still a member of Star Fleet.